# Why does the web page I fetch with Perl look odd?

Tags: html, perl, http, encryption

I have a Perl script to open the page http://svejo.net/popular/all/new/ and filter the names of the posts, but except headers, everything seems encrypted. Nothing can be read.

When I open the same page in a browser everything looks fine, including the source code. How is it possible to encrypt a page for a script and not for a browser? My Perl script sends the same headers as my browser (Google Chrome).

Comment: No idea what you're doing in perl, but this works fine for me with curl.  How do you know it's encrypted?

Comment: Show us the minimal but complete script you are using and the output you are getting.

Comment: When you say `except headers everything seems encrypted` do you mean the 'text/information' only, or 'text and html tags'?

Comment: everything after the blank line that indicates end of the server response message is a mess.

Answer (score 4):

The page looks fine to me, although I don't read Bulgarian.

```
#!perl

use LWP::Simple;

getprint( 'http://svejo.net/popular/all/new/' );
```

This script returns the plain page without anything that looks odd or encrypted:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="bg" lang="bg">
  <head>

<title>Svejo — Популярните новини </title>
```

What were you trying, and which versions of perl and the modules are you using? What is the output that you are seeing?

You clarify that you are using ActivePerl on Windows (please update your question with additional details). Remember, not only do you need to do the right Unicode things in your programs, but your terminal has to be set up to display Unicode properly.

---

What happens when you explicitly [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) your output?

```
 binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
```

Try saving the output to a file and looking at it in an editor that understands UTF-8.

---

Okay, that didn't work. Let's get even more general and set all handles to use UTF-8 by default:

```
  use open IO  => ':utf8';
```

Comment: @brian - that's cyrillic but hardly Russian :) If you look at the source, the language is right there: <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="bg" /> - so it's Bulgarian (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulgarian_language). As Stevko says, it's UTF-8, or at least so claims my Firefox :)

Comment: By the way, my ActiveState Perl (v5.10.1) - at least in WindowsXP cmd terminal windows - indeed renders the Cyrillic as some sort of upper-ASCII-art-characters-gibberish using your Perl 2-liner above. I'm not well versed enough with UTF to venture a plausible reason :(

Comment: I'm using OpeSuse, Perl version is 5.10.0, the terminal is set to utf8. I even redirected script output to a file - same thing. Obviously perl is using different character encoding than utf8. By the way I tried replacing the connection part of the script with a simple `curl -i http://svejo.net/thestuffhere` (enclosed in backticks) and it works. Now I'm really confused

Comment: Okay, this is really strange, and a bit hard to figure out remotely. Can you post the compilation details for your perl with `perl -V`? Also, is this a packaged perl or one you compiled yourself? I'd try compiling another perl to see what happens. That's a drastic measure though.

Comment: it was built in the distro. I will post the details as a new answer

Answer (score 2):

The page is encoded with UTF-8.
Perhaps your Perl script is using a different encoding?

I found this page that describes [Processing UTF-8 Files with Perl](http://ripary.com/utf8.html).

Comment: I guess this is the problem, but I can't figure out how to tell perl to use utf8. I read that by default it uses exactly utf8.